# SQL query with subqueries, joining multiple tables - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

The tables are:

```
1) Producers: id, name
2) Products: id, name, price, category_id, producer_id
3) Customers: id, name, surname, age, country_id
4) Customer_orders: id, customer_id, product_id, quantity, discount, order_date
```

I need to find the prodcuer, who's income was the highest, in other words: find a producer for which the sum of all prodcut `price * quantity - discount` is the highest.

I suppose, that I should join table `customer_orders` with `product_id` column on `products`, and `products` with `producers` table on column `id` and then calculate the appropriate income for all producers and then find the maximum value.

The problem is, how to write in in MySql.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: nothing worth mentioning, need some tips how to begin with such a query

Answer (score 1):

You can start with something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(price - discount) income, producers.name name FROM customer_orders LEFT JOIN products ON customer_orders.product_id = products.id LEFT JOIN producers ON producers.id = products.producer_id GROUP BY producer_id
```

I'm not sure if that will work exactly how I typed it but it should be a starting point.

Here are some helpful links:

[`Left Joins`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-left-joins.htm) [`Sum Function`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp)

Please note: I'm currently working on a server where the tables are structured like this, and it's super slow and a pain to get anything done. I'd encourage you to consider at least adding the total order about and the `producer_id` to the `customer_orders` table to make it a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is summarize the order values per producer. The order value is defined by price, quantity and discount. Since only the last 2 can be found in the customer_orders table, you'll have to join the Products table.
This can be done with the following query:

```
select * from customer_orders
inner join products on products.id = customer_orders.product_id
```

But since we're supposed to group them by the producer, we'd need the name or id of the producer as well, so we also have to join the producers table:

```
select * from customer_orders
inner join products on products.id = customer_orders.product_id
inner join producers on producers.id = products.producer_id
```

Now you're selecting all the information you need. To do the calculations you need to replace the asterisk with:

```
(customer_orders.quantity * customer_orders.discount) - products.price
```

which will give you the value of each order.

To sum all the order for a given producer, you need to wrap the above line in a `SUM()` function, and you need to add a `GROUP BY` clause at the end of the query.

```
select SUM( (customer_orders.quantity * customer_orders.discount) - products.price) as value, producers.name from customer_orders
inner join products on products.id = customer_orders.product_id
inner join producers on producers.id = products.producer_id
group by producers.name
```